# Response Code is 0 when using Status404NotFound

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404

I'm using AspNetCore 1.1.3 to create some endpoints and swagger to check them.

When using Resonse codes:

```
Status401Unauthorized
Status403Forbidden
```

Swagger tells me the response code is 401/403 like i would expect.

> But when i use Status404NotFound swagger shows 0 as the response code and body is:

```
{
    "error": "no response from server"
}
```

I'm using the following lines to return status code and body. There is no other change.

```
Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;  // or Status403Forbidden
return new JsonResult("{\"statusCode\":404}");    // 403
```

Is this expected behaviour? I would like to use the response codes in my application for error handling and 404 returning empty statuscode/body is not really useful.

Comment: Where is `StatusCodes` coming from? That's not from .NET Core. The correct enum is `HttpStatusCode`, and here you'd be using `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`.

Comment: @ChrisPratt StatusCodes is from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.StatusCodes. It doesn't really matter as the code is just int 404 anyway.

Comment: We're assuming. Also, it matters in the sense that ASP.NET Core is fully tested, so I know that `HttpStatusCode.NotFound` is 404 when cast to an int. I have no idea *what* the value of `StatusCodes.Status404NotFound` is of even if it exists at all.

Comment: Status404NotFound is defindes as `public const int Status404NotFound = 404;` There is no need to cast. I can also just replace it with plain `404` or `(int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound` and get the same result.